# How to get colored map in HyperTrack?

Tags: android, hypertrack

HyperTrack map is always grey scaled. Is there any way to change it to colored maps as provided by Google Maps API.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your request. This is Abhishek here from HyperTrack.

We don't yet have a customization option to change the color theme of the map. I will take up this request with the team to make it available. Will add it to other map view customizations that we have available (https://docs.hypertrack.com/usecases/livetracking/android/customizations/map.html).

Btw, is there a specific color theme that you are looking for?

Comment: I think the original maps of Google maps will do for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `map_style.json` file inside res/raw/ folder of your app.

`Default Map Style`

> Content of **map_style.json**

```
[
  {
    "stylers": [
      {
        "saturation": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can also create a different style of map using [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) of google maps.